# Good WebCam Recording Application

Tags: software-rec, recording, webcam

I'm looking for a freeware/opensource application which allows me to:

- access my webcam
- record directly from my webcam (including sound!)

Editing is not necessary, I'll do it with VirtualDub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, I found out [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) can do it too. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Windows Movie Maker (here's a **[portable version](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk)** with all the goodies incl. webcam capturing)

**[ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/)** is very popular, handy if you want to add nice effects to your webcam.

*both programs are freeware.*

Answer (score 1):

There's [WebCam Recorder](http://webcamrecorder.com/).

I've not used it, but from the description it seems to do everything you want.

However, [this blog post](http://www.jakeludington.com/ask_jake/20080125_how_to_record_webcam_videos.html) (while plugging some other recorder) states:

> You can use Windows Movie Maker, which comes with Windows XP and Vista

so you might not need to install anything else.